# firebase deploy: Error: path-to-file/firestore.indexes.json does not exist

Tags: firebase

I added the functions folder for firebase cloud functions. But now I can not deploy my `Angular` project. When I deploy only the function with `firebase deploy --only functions` it works fine but when I try to deploy my project by running `firebase deploy`, I get this error:

```
Error: desktop/projects/my-angular-project/firestore.indexes.json does not exist
```

my `firebase.json` file :

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/functions/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `firebase.json` files has an instruction to deploy security rules and predefined indexes to Firestore here:

```
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
```

If you don't want either of these to happen, remove that line from the `firebase.json`.

Comment: I think this was added to `firebase.json` after I ran `firebase init functions`. But it somehow did not generate the files

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reinitializing the firebase project `firebase init`. This time two files were generated in the root directory `firebase.rules` and `firebase.indexes.json` which were not there for some reason and the problem was solved.